# Create a dropdown list when a row is added using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

I want to write a macro that does as  follows:
If you enter a value under column A, it gives a dropdown list in the same row under column B.

I have written a peice which works for the first time. But the problem is when I run it, if there is already a dropdown list in some cells, it breaks!

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim cell As Range

'If a value is listed
  For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A1000")
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        If Selection = Empty Then
            With Selection.Validation
                'add list box
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!A2:A20"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

I should add that I cannot delete the content in column B, because I do not want to lose the work already there.

Comment: Quick clarification on not deleting info in Column B.  You plan on running this more than once.  Why? Is data going to change? If so, shouldn't the validation change too? Or do you want to keep old info there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you clear existing data validation before adding the new one?

Along these lines:

```
        With Selection.Validation
            ' delete existing
            .Delete
            'add list box
            .Add Type etc.
```

The Validation.Delete does the same thing as clicking "Clear All" in the data validation dialog. No cell content gets changed or removed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot delete the content in column B, because I do not want to lose the work already there. I added this to the question.

Comment: No content is deleted in column B. The data validation is removed, then another data validation is added. Have you even tried it?

Comment: I added a screenshot to help you understand what the setting does.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that will just delete a validation, then add back.  Also, I removed the use of `.Select`, which can cause errors.

```
Dim isValid As Boolean

Sub Macro2()
Dim cell As Range

'If a value is listed
  For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A1000")
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        testIfValidation cell.Offset(0, 1)
        If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 1)) And Not isValid Then
            With cell.Offset(0, 1).Validation
                'add list box
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!A2:A20"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub

Private Sub testIfValidation(ByVal cel As Range)
Dim X As Variant
On Error Resume Next
X = cel.Validation.Type
On Error GoTo 0
If IsEmpty(X) Then
    Debug.Print cel.Address & " has no validation"
    isValid = False
Else
    isValid = True
End If
End Sub
```

I updated this with a test to see if a cell has validation. If it does, it'll skip it.  Otherwise, proceed as usual.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot delete the content in column B, because I do not want to lose the work already there. I added this to the question.

Comment: Only the data validation setting gets deleted, no content is harmed. Same as in my suggestion.

Comment: @Ana - See my updated code. I added a global variable, and a sub that will check if a cell is valid.

Comment: This is a correct answer, too. I just picked the other answer because it was simpler, and upvoted this answer.

Comment: @Ana - Ah okay. I thought you wanted to keep the info, but I suppose not.  However, I ***highly*** recommend removing the use of `.Select`, and work directly with the data (see my code as to how you can do that).